# Accessing content of each list of a list of list in Python

Tags: python, list, loops

It seems a bit convoluted printed like this, but what I want should be quite simple.
I have a list of list in Python.

Lets say `list = [[A, B, C], [D, B], [E], [X, Y, Z]]`

I want to iterate over the elements of each inner list following a certain order
I tried

```
for i in range(0, 10):
    for item in list[i]:
        <do action on item>
```

But I get a syntax error from Python pointing to `list[i]`, doesn't seem to like it very much.

EDIT : I want to iterate through one inner list at a time
For example :

```
for i in range(0, 1):
    print i
    for item in list[i] #or something that works..
        print item
```

would print

```
0
A
B
C
1
D
B
```

Any idea why this is blocking ?

And the traceback simply says that there is a syntax error there ...

RE-EDIT : I solved my problem by using an other data structure. It was a bit over complicated. Sorry for wasting your time, but thanks for the tips anyway !

Comment: What is the error, the traceback?

Comment: Maybe just add the missing colon?  If you would actually show us the full traceback, it would be a matter of seconds to solve this.  Refusing to do so is a big waste of time.

Comment: It's just because I refer to other functions every line it is a bit over complicated I think and my problem was only related to this very part. I solved my problem though by using a different structure.

Answer (score 5):

This is because your outer list has only 4 elements, and thus does not have an index 4 (or 5 or 6, etc). This is why you are getting an index error.

It's analogous to this:

> > > L = [1, 2, 3]
> > >       L[6] # L does not have a  6th index
> > >           Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >             File "", line 1, in 
> > >           IndexError: list index out of range

What you should do instead, is this:

```
for sub_list in L:
    for item in sub_list:
        <do action on item>
```

**In response to your edit:**

As a note, don't use types as variable names. So don't call your list list. Perhaps this is where some of the dislike is coming from.

If the error is something to the effect of "type is not subscriptable", then this is exactly why you are getting the error. You can fix it by changing the name of `list` to something else - I would recommend `L`

Comment: As a note, this method makes looping through lists much easier in general. You no longer have to worry about keeping track of how long the list is. Using iterators to your advantage is a key to idiomatic python.

Comment: This is a useful note indeed. But in my case, I don't think it the reason why it crashes : The error appears when I try to run the program. At this time it doesn't even know how long the list is.. Btw I edited my post, provided more details on what I want to do

Comment: I just used the name list for the example here, I don't use it in my code. My piece of code is a bit more complicated than that so I simplified it.

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking for

```
for my_list in list_of_lists:
    for item in my_list:
        # whatever
```

Comment: Also, if you want the item's index, don't forget to use the `enumerate` command: `for i, my_list in enumerate(list_of_lists):`

Comment: Thanks for all the quick replies, I realize I wasn't clear enough : I edited my post

Comment: How does this answer not accomplish what you set out in your edit?

Comment: Because I have another loop just above, it would iterate too many times. But this is too complicated to achieve, I found a simpler way with a different data structure

Answer (score 2):

What you want is to chain the sublists and iterate. Itertools module has a function to do this, and is very simple and efficient:

```
for item in itertools.chain.from_iterable(list_of_lists):
   <do action on item>
```

Comment: Or `itertools.chain(*list_of_lists):`; using `from_iterable` only seems to be really useful when you want lazy evaluation/are working with an iterable that returns a large number of values.

Answer (score 2):

maybe you get an error because you used range(0,10) but your list does not have 10 entries?

```
l = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'b'], ['e'], ['x', 'y', 'z']]
for i in range (0,len(l)):
    for item in l[i]:
        print item

a
b
c
d
b
e
x
y
z
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error may be related to `i` being greater than the number of inner lists. To avoid this you could instead use

```
for inner in list:
    for item in inner:
        <do action on item>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use something like this too:

```
l = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'b'], ['e'], ['x', 'y', 'z']]
[val for row in l for val in row]
```

Or in case you need to perform any action:

```
for val in (val for row in l for val in row):
    # do smth
```

OR:

```
action = lambda x: str(x)+'_1'
[map(lambda val: action(val), row) for row in l]
```

OR:

```
action = lambda x: str(x)+'_1'
map(lambda row: map(lambda val: action(val), row), l)
```

Comment: Nested list and generator comprehensions still kind of throw me off due to the end value being on the left but the inner loops proceeding to the right.

Comment: @JAB what do you mean ? I'm not sure I understand properly how it works

Comment: @Johanna: `for row in l for val in row` is equivalent to `for row in l:\n\tfor val in row:`